# Localhost with Flutter web not working with docker

Tags: docker, flutter, docker-compose, dockerfile, flutter-web

I was trying to run a flutter web application but I can't see it running in `localhost`.
I have this message that is running but I can't see it in my browser.

> dashboard_1  | lib/main.dart is being served at http://localhost:8080

Dockerfile

```js
FROM cirrusci/flutter AS build

RUN apt update && apt install -y nginx

RUN flutter channel beta
RUN flutter upgrade
RUN flutter config --enable-web

RUN mkdir /app/
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN flutter build web
```

docker-compose.yml

```js
version: '3.1'
services:
    dashboard:
        build: .
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: >
            sh -c "flutter pub get && flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080"
```

Comment: If an application prints out "listening on `localhost`" at startup, it probably won't be reachable from outside the container; you need to reconfigure it somehow to listen to (or set the bind address to) 0.0.0.0 instead.  See for example [Why 0.0.0.0 is working and localhost or 127.0.01 is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197982/why-0-0-0-0-is-working-and-localhost-or-127-0-01-is-not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added `--web-hostname 0.0.0.0` to end of the `docker-compose.yml` command and it works. But instead of `localhost:8080` now is `0.0.0.0:8080`.

So the `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```js
version: '3.1'
services:
    dashboard:
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: >
            sh -c "flutter pub get && flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Solved. Thanks!